# Why is proxy bypassed for https requests to a server on the LAN

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy

I have written a node-based forward proxy which works fine with http and https when external sites are visited.  However, I have a problem for local sites, that is sites hosted on the same LAN. The proxy appears to be bypassed for https://www.example.com but is not bypassed for http://www.example.com, where example.com is hosted locally on the same LAN.

My /etc/environment is set to (output of env|grep -i proxy):

```
NO_PROXY=localhost
http_proxy=http://192.168.1.80:5500/
ftp_proxy=ftp://192.168.1.168:3128/
socks_proxy=socks://192.168.1.168:3128/
https_proxy=https://192.168.1.80:5500/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.1.80:5500/
no_proxy=localhost
HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.80:5500/
```

I have a reverse proxy set which accepts the connection over https or http and forwards it to my internal servers which are on the same machine but running on different ports. The connection to the reverse proxy is secured over https but from there to the internal server is unsecured, over http. Also, all requests to http://www.example.com are redirected by the reverse proxy to https://www.example.com first.

My main problem is that both Chrome and Firefox bypass the proxy for the site hosted on the same LAN, even though I am accessing it via a publicly registered domain name. The proxy works fine for all external sites.

Is there something I need to set in these browsers or for the Linux environment variables?

Comment: What does bypass the proxy mean? What do both the webserver and proxy logs tell you?  Key things to look for a redirects

Comment: @Nath Bypass the proxy means that the request goes to the web server directly and not through the forward proxy. All the servers are custom built by me... I mean using Node. So, I know what I am logging, how, etc. My forward proxy does not even get the https request to the local site.